# How to check disabled select element and I want to change opacity of disabled element by checking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magento-1.9

```
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__($_attribute->getLabel()) ?></label></dt>
    <dd <?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
        <div class="input-box">
            <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
              </select>
          </div>
    </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </dl>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>,   <?php echo $this->getProductsStockStatus()?>);
    var ProChildData = <?php echo $this->getProductsStockStatus()?>;
   </script>
```

This is a code of a template on which hidden is applied when no image is selected through external js.
I want to check it and then want to add opacity in the disabled element till select option is not enabled.
Thanks in advanced.Feel free to give suggestion devs.Every suggestion is valuable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `css` syle. you can do like this.

```
select option:disabled{
    opacity: 0;
 }
```

For slelect element

```
select:disabled{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still it's not working at all.Select is disabled but no opacity applied.

Comment: <select name="super_attribute[187]" id="attribute187" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" disabled="">
                    <option>Kies een optie...</option>
                  </select> this is a select tag.

Comment: Thanks, bro it works for me :-) Short and easiest way without checking with js and jquery stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it disabled as desired, and then remove the disabled attribute before the form is submitted.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $('select').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Note that if you rely on this method, you'll want to disable it programmatically as well, because if JS is disabled or not supported, you'll be stuck with the disabled select.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```